# Add classes to tags in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags

I'd just like to add the name of each tag as a class so that I can target each one individually with CSS. I've done extensive searches on this and most results are referring to putting the class on the body or post, or point me in the direction of here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_tags

I'm sure I could acheive this from extracting the correct info from this article but my php and wordpress knowledge is limited so I can't figure out how to do what I require specifically.

Eg - 
`<a rel="tag" href="">black</a>` would become `<a rel="tag" href="" class="black">black</a>`

BTW these tags are product tags in woocommerce, but I'm guessing this makes no difference?

Comment: Use jquery to add Class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below JS code.

This does the magic,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
        var tst = $(this).html();
        $( this ).addClass( tst );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've tried modifying it to fit where my tags are sitting but no joy, I guess I'm not getting it.
`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".tagged_as a" ).each(function( index ) {
        var tst = $(this).html();
        $( this ).addClass( tst );
    });
});
</script>`

I've put that code in header.php, is that correct?

Comment: `<span class="tagged_as">
Tags:
<a rel="tag" href="http://localhost:8888/integral-vitality/product-tag/vegan/">Vegan</a>
,
<a rel="tag" href="http://localhost:8888/integral-vitality/product-tag/vegetarian/">Vegetarian</a>
,
<a rel="tag" href="http://localhost:8888/integral-vitality/product-tag/yeast-free/">Yeast Free</a>
.
</span>`

That's the html (woocommerce tags) and the js as above. Sorry it looks really messy posting it here in a comment!!

Comment: Is it correct to place the javascript in the header.php file, and am I targeting the correct thing according to my markup?

Comment: Yes thats right. You can either put in the header.php or footer.php.. Just replace the "$" symbol with "jQuery" in the script and try it. This may help you.

Comment: Hmmm still no classes appearing on those 'a' tags. Could there be a conflict or something?

Comment: Check your error console in your browser to check whether there is any  conflicts occuring. So that it will be fixed. Or else check whether the jquery file is included properly

Comment: Aha, changing ALL of the $ to jQuery worked! I thought that you meant just the first one... Thanks :)

Comment: Because in Wordpress sometimes "$" is not accepted since latest JS version use "jQuery"

Answer (score 2):

This PHP should add them without the use of javascript.

```
foreach (get_the_tags() as $tag) {
    echo "<a rel=\"tag\" href=\"\" class=\"" . $tag->name . "\">".$tag->name."</a> ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Where would I place this code? I tried it in the function.php file and nothing happened...

Comment: Where you want to display the tags, within the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what that means :-/ Do you mean in the php file that displays these tags, or within functions.php?

Comment: In the PHP file that displays these tags.

Comment: Is there an easy method to find out what that file is? I'm assuming it's within woocommerce folder in this case as they are woocommerce tags...

Comment: That would be a safe assumption, although I am unsure which file it is.

Comment: Hi, I've located where this code is and it reads as this:
`<?php echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>`

Comment: I have tried inserting your 'foreach' code both after the php tag, and completely outside with its own php tag and neither worked. Could you advise me on how/ where I would apply it according to this?